# XCode and SenTestingKit not outputting to the editor window

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, tdd, ios

I am new to testing in Xcode. I am following the developer documentation "iOS Developement Guide" Unit Testing Applications.

I have successfully added unit test bundles to my application with one failing test.

When I build the test target the output shows 1 error as expected but the editor does not show the expected error message under the failed test.

Does anyone know any configurations that need to be set to enable this feature?

Apples docs say:
"If the unit-test bundle is configured correctly, the build fails and Xcode displays an error message in the text editor."

TIA

Vital Clue: 
- One thing I have noticed in my output window is the message "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this [guide](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) 
Be double careful about when to set application target, and when to set Unit test target. It works fine for me though. 
If Unit Test fail, there should be some messages shown in the console.